# Reading a resource sound file into a Byte array

Tags: android, android-resources

I have `cheerapp.wav` or `cheerapp.mp3` or some other format.

```
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp);       
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in, 8000);
// Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data from the saved file
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

byte[] music = null;
music = new byte[??];
int i = 0; // Read the file into the "music" array
while (dis.available() > 0) {
    // dis.read(music[i]); // This assignment does not reverse the order
    music[i]=dis.readByte();
    i++;
}

dis.close();
```

For the `music` byte array which takes the data from the `DataInputStream`. I don't know what the length of that to allocate.

This is raw file from resource not a file therefore I wouldn't know the size of that thing.

Comment: Consider using [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do have byte array length as you can see:

```
 InputStream inStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp);
 byte[] music = new byte[inStream.available()];
```

And then you can read whole Stream into byte array easily.

Of course I would recommend that you do check when it comes to the size and use ByteArrayOutputStream with smaller byte[] buffer if needed:

```
public static byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
    int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buff, 0, i);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray(); // be sure to close InputStream in calling function
}
```

If you'll be doing lots of IO operations I recommend that you make use of [org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). That way you won't need to worry too much about quality of your IO implementation and once you import JAR into your project you would just do:

```
byte[] payload = IOUtils.toByteArray(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp));
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope it will help.

Create an sdcard path:

```
String outputFile = 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
```

Convert as a file and have to call the byte array method:

```
byte[] soundBytes;

try {
    InputStream inputStream = 
        getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(new File(outputFile)));

    soundBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    soundBytes = toByteArray(inputStream);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Recordin Finished"+ " " + soundBytes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

method:

```
public byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (read != -1) {
        read = in.read(buffer);
        if (read != -1)
            out.write(buffer,0,read);
    }
    out.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin use
`InputStream.readBytes()`