# Image size increased if image convert to byte array

Tags: java, android, image, httpurlconnection

I need to upload image (jpeg, png, gif) and audio (mp3, wav, aa3) to web server. So I need to convert image into byte array. How do I do that?

Now I am try following format. But it increases the size. How do other applications do this without increasing size quality? They upload the original size and image quality.

```
Bitmap uploadedImage = ((BitmapDrawable) temp.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
uploadedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: How does your application initially receive the image file? Are you reading it from disk?

Comment: Instead of storing image in a Database why dont you apend the timestamp and a unique identifier to its name and Ftp it to the server?

Comment: @Duncan initially i receive this from intent in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to compress. Just send as stream. once got the image uri do the following..

```
InputStream iStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

and use the `iStream` into write the httpsurlconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Original images increase in size when converted to a bitmap because all the image formats you mentioned use some form of compression (some lossless, some not). When you use a bitmap, there's no compression used.

You could read the raw data of the drawable into a byte array and send that to the server. You can check that answer [Reading a resource sound file into a Byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098657/reading-a-resource-sound-file-into-a-byte-array) to see an example of how this could be done.

Comment: Thank u for ur valuable reply

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have the Image in some sort of form already? Don't try to decompress or process it, just send it to the server as a stream of bytes. For example if it is already a file on your computer:

```
public String postFile(URL url, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    try {

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        try {
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(CHUNK_SIZE);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");

            try (OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE]; 
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != 201) {
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()))) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                }
            } else {
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                    // TODO: Handle success
                }
            }
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
}
```

To send a file just pass in the FileInputStream, to send bytes you can simplify the function above so it doesn't need to read from the stream and can just send the byte buffer on the output stream.

To get an InputStream for a local file you just need:

```
 File file = ....
 try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    postFile(url, is);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      // TODO: Handle error
 }
```

Comment: if i got image uri,could u please tell how to get stream.

Comment: Where is the image? A local file? A web page?

Comment: image is from local file