# how to get bytes from wav in android studio

Tags: android, audio

i read lots of code for read byte from wav for android studio

but i  still can not get byte from wav

really need codes or demo so i can get what i need

whats wrong with my code

```
Resources inn = getResources();
    InputStream in = inn.openRawResource(R.raw.ccheer);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in, 8000);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    byte[] music = null;
    music = new byte[1024];
    int i = 0; 
    try {
        while (dis.available() > 0) {

            music[i]=dis.readByte();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Does it hit the exception?  What is the exception message?

Comment: here is the answer [use this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15098868/6619302)

Comment: Are you trying to read in the data as audio? Are you wanting to count the number of audio frames? Does Android make use of Java's AudioInputStream and AudioFormat classes?

Comment: im trying to read audio data and modify data,so i can get the modified wav. im not sure how to use audioinputstream and audioformat .

Comment: i need to pick wav from sdcard or other folders.read byte and write data back to  wav file.but i still cant read byte .i try that answer but there are somthing wrong to my code .

Answer (score 0):

here is my new code. still cant read byte[]

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        System.out.println("Uri: " + uri);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getRealPathFromURI(this,uri));

    }

}

public static byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int length = 0;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

whats wrong ? just want to read like this or other way ...

byte 00

byte 11

byte 22
...